# A problem with the `cli` package the is affecting `ggfortify` and `tidyr` packages?

Tags: r, error-handling, download, r-package

When loading my libraries, the 2 libraries of `ggfortify` and `tidyr` are not working.

What I did is as follows :

I updated R to the 4.2.2 version.

I used the update command for all the packages.

I installed again the library `cli` with dependencies = TRUE as an argument.

The error looks as follows

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggfortify’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘cli’ 3.3.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required
```

Comment: Stop R. Try to start it _without any packages loaded_.  (Re-)install `cli`. That should give a recent-enough version to satisfy the versioned dependency you are seeing.

Comment: You mean by stop to end the session and restart it again ? if that so, I just tried it, and reopened it again and before loading the packages, I reinstalled the `cli` package but still the same problem :(

Comment: The point is to make _really sure_ you are not already attaching packages via a saved session etc.  Open R, do `search()` and you should only see base packages. _If you see `cli` in that list you have problem._ This issue is known and common (hence closed as duplicate).  One good fix is to frequently run `update.packages()` to keep things current.

Comment: search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"    
 [4] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
 [7] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
[10] "package:base"

Comment: That's how it appears. So there is a problem right ?

Comment: I’m wondering if your Autoloads includes packages that are not being listed ?   Also run `sessionInfo()` and see if that shows the cli package and it’s version.

Comment: yes exactly it includes it when using `sessioninfo()`

Comment: I got it work. I removed the package and then redownload it thank you two so much